# Maximum value for unsigned int?

Tags: c++, unsigned

I wrote a program to find the last Fibonacci number using type `unsigned int`. It is `1836311903` but I thought the max values for an `unsigned int` is `65535`. So what's going on?

```
while(true)
    {
        sequence[j] = sequence[j-1] + sequence[j-2];
        if(sequence[j-1]>sequence[j]) break;
        j++;
    }

    printf("%d", sequence[j-2]);
```

Comment: Unless you have 2 byte `unsigned int`s, the max number in `unsigned int` is definitely bigger than 65535.

Comment: How do you “know” that the largest `unsigned int` is 65535?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mistaken in your belief that max number for unsigned int is 65535. That hasn't been the case for most compilers since perhaps early days of windows 95 when we had 16-bit processors.

The standards do NOT define the size of any integral type; they only define the relationship of the sizes between one another.  (long long >= long >= int >= short >= char... etc)  The actual sizes though incredibly common and consistent are defined by the implementation of your compiler and thus are generally platform defined.

That not withstanding most int's use the size of a word on the processor; which today is often 32bits or 64bits.

You could verify 'why' yourself by taking sizeof(int); then raise 2 to that power subtract 1 and you've got your answer for max int...

A better way would be to `#include <limits.h>` or `#include <climits>` and use the values it defines.
In `C++` you can use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` as well.

Comment: In c++, we would actually use [`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max).

Comment: Yes I'm aware, I went off C standard since I knew it better. I'll add that in

Comment: @sharth is that a c++11 thing?

Comment: No. It's been around since at least the first c++ standard in 1998.

Answer (score 4):

As shown in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm (and many other places), unsigned int can be 2 bytes or 4 bytes. In your case, you are using 4 bytes so the maximum is 4,294,967,295.

The maximum you mention, 65535 corresponds to 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the max value for an unsigned int on your system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int        ui;

int main()
{
    ui uimax = ~0;

    printf("uimax  %u\n",uimax);

    return 0;
}
```

Int types only define the relationship between their sizes not their actual size e.g.

unsigned long long int >= unsigned long int >= unsigned int >= unsigned short int >= unsigned char

Comment: It would be clearer to use one of the built-in facilities to get the maximum size.

Comment: By clearer do you mean easier?? Its just I don't know how much clearer I can get... Sorry I'm a noob at this forum stuff.....

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`, although wordy, makes the intention of the value clear.